# Subdomain resolving to 2 different IP addresses (one unknown)

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, a-record

I have a domain registered with Fasthosts (animesoc.co.uk). I've recently hosted a forum on an external server (with IP address 51.254.128.170), and pointed the subdomain http://forums.animesoc.co.uk/ to this by adding the corresponding A record.

The issue is that when I try accessing 'forums.animesoc.co.uk' through a browser (tried from multiple different computers), it keeps switching between the website I actually want and a blank domain parking page with advertisements. It resolves to the IP address I mentioned above for about 1 hour or so, then starts giving me the domain parking page, switches back again to the forums and so on and so forth.

On using a DNS resolver service like http://tracert.com/resolver to check what the 'forums' subdomain resolves to, I get the following result

> Resolution of forums.animesoc.co.uk resulted in the following IPv4 addresses:
>
> 51.254.128.170
>
> 213.171.195.105

I'm not sure why it's resolving to two IP addresses when I have only the single A record for forums (pointing to 51.254.128.170). Furthermore, I do not have the IP '213.171.195.105' present anywhere in my DNS settings so I'm not sure where that's come from.

I assume that the switching between the actual website and the domain parking page is occurring due to the subdomain resolving to this extra '213.171.195.105' IP address as well. **How can I make the subdomain 'forums.animesoc.co.uk' resolve to just one single IP address (51.254.128.170)?**

Comment: As you've identified, your nameservers are returning multiple IP addresses for that A record. We cannot troubleshoot this with the information you've provided. This is a configuration problem in the DNS server software, and if you are 100% certain that you are making the changes in the correct web interface the problem will need to be discussed with the product's support eam.

Comment: Did you make this change _today_? You may simply have seen old, cached DNS records. I no longer see the livedns IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, the problem was with the domain host as Andrew suggested. They fixed it pretty quickly, which is why you must've seen the corrected result when you checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with the domain host's settings as Andrew suggested in the comments above. The issue was resolved after I contacted them to remove the rogue A record from the domain.